# Chrome extension infinite while loops

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension, and I need to make an infinite while loop in it, but whenever the while loop starts, the browser tab crashes. Is there any solution or other method I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need an infinite loop? What are you  trying to achieve?

There are other options like [`window.requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) or [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) that you could use inside a page to continuously do something without blocking it. For example:

```js
const counterElement = document.getElementById('counter');

let counterValue = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  counterElement.innerText = (++counterValue / 100).toFixed(2); 
}, 10);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 48px 8px 8px;
  font-family: monospace;
}

#counter {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

hr {
  border: none;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  margin: 32px 0;
}

button {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  font-family: monospace;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

button:hover {
  background: yellow;
}

button:active {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

button:focus {
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 7px 11px;
}
```

```html
<div id="counter">0</div>

Click around the page. See how everything still works?

<hr />

<button>BUTTON</button>
<button>BUTTON</button>
```

You could also consider a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) depending on your needs.

Comment: @BomberF35 Did this solve your problem? If so, could you please accept the answer (click the checkmark under the points). That will help other users that come across your question quickly spot the accepted answer and it also gives 15 rep. points to the author (: